# fill text elements in flash from word document (segments)

Tags: flash, ms-word, macromedia

I need to get text segments from separate word documents into flash text elements.

Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 1):

Only with server side scripting. You need a server side mechanism to extract the desired parts from the Word documents, and call this script with appropriate arguments from your flash app to fetch those parts.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Hanak's answer: See the section "Let Office do the heavy work for you"

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html

Answer (score 0):

I would think your best bet would be to get the text into an xml document and load that text into flash from there. You won't be able to load the text from the .doc file directly.  As for getting the text into xml I would think it'd have to be a manual job, or, if there is some logic to how the text is structured you could write a macro to pull the text out for you.